# PDO Class Caching Issue

Tags: php, pdo

For a few days now one of my class files doesn't seem to be recognizing the updates I'm making to it, and I can't figure out why.  I've verified the server has the most current copy and also tried deleting the file off the server and uploading a clean copy.  I've even removed functions entirely from the class and then successfully ran those functions from another file even though I'm positive it was no longer in the class file.

I don't know what the issue is, but I'm guessing it may be some type of cache issue?  Tried rebooting the server too, same issue.  I've also poured through the code and can't find any errors.  Here's a link to the file [http://pastebin.com/eiki93GM](http://pastebin.com/eiki93GM/).

What are some of the possible issues?

Comment: So, what's the problem?  You're updating a PHP file, but it's still running the "old version"?  How do you know it's not using your new code?

Comment: Because, like mentioned above, I've removed entire functions from the class and then executed them from another file (pointing to the function in the class file) and it still ran that function, even though it was no longer in the class. I did this to narrow down the possible issues because I can't find any coding errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two

- opcode cache with disabled filemtime check.
- you are uploading to the wrong server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look into the opcode cache now.. I am  uploading to the correct server though